# SQL Server Query that Updates Based on a Select - ISSUES

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am writing a query that basically updates all date fields for EstimatedDepartureDate to a specified date. I am using a view I created to pull a list of accounts to update and running this against my tnpEmployee table which has all employee records. When running this query however, it always has an output similar to:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (55 row(s) affected)

As in, it's affecting one row first and then the rest. And when I go to run the SQL in that view I created to see the list of persons of interest, it shows one record less with every run of the query, as well as one number less in that bottom (55 row(s) affected), so the next run would show 54.

Here is the query I'm running:

```
UPDATE tnpEmployee 
SET tnpEmployee.EstimatedDepartureDate='2014-04-01 13:37:43.000'
FROM tnpEmployee
INNER JOIN vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled
ON tnpEmployee.EmployeeID=vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled.EmployeeID
WHERE tnpEmployee.Email=vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled.Email
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's killing me! All that needs to happen is the rows get that date field set and that's it, they should all populate in the very basic view I created, not one less on every run. Also, when I run that view and get one record less, ALL the records have been updated with the new date..

Comment: One possibility is that the table `tmpEmployee` has an update trigger.  Can you see what triggers are on the table?

Comment: I was just going to say "look for a trigger". That update statement alone would do everything in one batch, so it shouldn't show two "x rows affected" lines.

Comment: WHy are you updating a view and not the table directly?

Comment: And the trigger shoudl be looked at to see if it is set up top correctly handle multiple rcord inserts, too many devlopers think triggers run row by row and they do not in SQL Server.

Comment: You guys are wonderful! Indeed there was a trigger that updates a different field when the EstimatedDepartureDate is updated. <3

Answer (score 0):

You could try to rewrite your SQL statement:

```
UPDATE tnpEmployee 
SET tnpEmployee.EstimatedDepartureDate='2014-04-01 13:37:43.000'
WHERE tnpEmployee.EmployeeID IN (
SELECT vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled.EmployeeID
FROM vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled
WHERE tnpEmployee.Email=vnpGetActiveAccountsAgainstToBeDisabled.Email
);
```

As the experts already suggested, your result looks like your query invokes a trigger.